# How fast is Yii RBAC?

Tags: performance, yii, rbac

I am building up an rbac implementation in Yii and first I would like to know how fast the system is. People who used it already in bigger projects can help me maybe. Is it a good idea to let the developers to assign Operations to Roles (isn't it better, when developers just use more Tasks for grouping (allowing to assign Tasks to a Task) the Operations)?
[image: Tasks and Roles]

and Imagine there is a thousand operation and a massive amount of Task beneath the Roles.
So, basically, how fast is this compared to other systems?

Answer (score 0):

I have proposed a patch for Yii's CDBAuthManager
(which you might use as I do in a form of extension class if you don't want to patch the code)

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1533#issuecomment-9207350

and there is a discussion here

p_180057#entry180057">http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37216-holy-cdbauthmanager-queries-batman/page_*p*_180057#entry180057

in general the bottle neck is having a recursive query to resolve the roles.
and caching would solve this, you should call purge in your `afterSave` of Auth-related models